# React hot loader not showing changes in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I see this question has been asked before. But none of them worked for me. When I change the code, the console shows

> [WDS] App hot update...

but I don't see the changes happening in the browser. I am using latest `react-hot-loader`, `webpack^2.2.0-rc.0` and the same version of `webpack-dev-server`. This is my webpack configuration file

```
const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'react', 'lodash', 'redux', 'react-redux', 'react-dom',
  'react-input-range', 'redux-form', 'fabric'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    // publicPath: 'dist/'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            loader: 'css-loader'
          }),
          test: /\.css$/,
        },
        {
          use: 'babel-loader',
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: { limit: 40000 }
            },
            'image-webpack-loader'
          ],
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        },
      ],
    },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  },
};
```

**babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
    }
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware());

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConvertImage />
    </Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am using `system.imports` in routing for async routing.

Answer (score 0):

In packages.json you need to have something like:
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --host 0.0.0.0",

Comment: I have webpack-dev-server but not inline flag . I will give this a try.

Comment: i did webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --host but did not work. It is same, no changes is seen on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the embedded HMR API at runtime to accept changes from the server. At a minimum, you need to add the following somewhere in your entrypoint script:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept()
}
```

Have a look at the [code sample](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/#code) provided in the new documentation to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make little changes to your `index.js` code

1. Import RHL
2. IF ELSE check to enable Hot loading or not
3. Wrap it around AppContainer.

Your code will more or less looks like this.

```
// Your other deps go here
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

const App = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware());

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConvertImage />
    </Provider>
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <App />
    </AppContainer>, document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
else {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("stub"));
}
```

Also, add Your 'react-hot-loader/patch' to the entry array in webpack config